# Why I'm always getting an Internal Server Error (code 500) after making a request to BackEnd

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, request, hosting

I'm having a little trouble with my site and I can't understand what is happening.
First of all I have to say that I was NOT having this behavior when developing on localhost, but now that my site is close to be completed I think that uploading my code to a hosting service and make some tests there would be a good idea.

The issue is that when I make a request to the database, most of the times the site keeps in an eternal loading state, until the error code 500: Internal Server Error appears (I said "most of the times" because it works nice sometime, but normally it remains in a pending state).

Given the fact that SOME TIMES the request work nice, makes me think that the issue is not on the server.js file (where I defined the endpoints), and also is not on my controllers files (where I have some logic and the requests itself).

I'll leave here some pics as example of what is happening but if you need some extra info just tell me:

A simple login example, I just fill the fields and send the request
[image: Step one: Login and send request]

And here you can see how the request remain as pending
[image]
[image]

Until it fails
[image]

**EDIT**: I'm using package Mysql2 to connect to the DB, and I was reading that this behavior may be because a bad use of connections (and I'm reading about "pools", but I'm kinda lost tbh)

Here is the connection file:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const mysql = require("mysql2");

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    waitForConnections: true,
});

const connection = async () => {
    db.connect((err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Successfully connected");
    })
}

exports.db = db;
exports.connection = connection;
```

The first call to the DB (just to check the connection)

```
connection().then(() => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server running at ...`);
    });
});
```

And the login logic

```
app.post("/dev-end/api/login", async (req, res) => {
     await singleAccount(db, req.body.email)
        .then(async (response) => {
            if (response.code) {
                res.render("templateLogin");
             }
            try {
                if (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, response.password)) {
                    const user = { id: response._id, name: response.name };
                    await deleteTokenById(db, user.id.toString());
                    const accessToken = generateAccessToken(user);
                    const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
                        user,
                        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                        { expiresIn: "604800s" }
                    );
                    createToken(db, {
                        _id: user.id,
                        accessToken: accessToken,
                        refreshToken: refreshToken,
                        createdAt: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " "),
                    }).then(
                        res
                            .cookie("access_token", accessToken, {
                                httpOnly: true,
                                maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24 * 7,
                            })
                            .redirect("/dev-end/dashboard")
                    );
                } else {
                    res.render("templateLogin");
                }
            } catch {
                res.status(500).send();
            }
        })
        .catch(console.log);
});
```

=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>

```
const singleAccount = async (conn, email) => {
    return await read(conn).then((res) => {
        if (!res.code) {
            const result = res.find((e) => e.email.toString() === email);
            if (!result) {
                return {
                    code: 404,
                    msg: "No account was found with the provided id",
                };
            }
            return result;
        }
        return res;
    });
};
```

=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>=>

```
const read = async (conn) => {
    const sql = `SELECT * FROM accounts`;
    return await conn.promise().query(sql)
        .then(([res, fields]) => res);
};
```

Comment: 120s looks more like a timeout than an actual crash, is it only the same URL that causes troubles ? EDIT: will be hard to help without code or logs.

Comment: @AR7CORE thx for the answer. This issue happens in all of the request to the DB, is not exclusive to the login. I just use it as example. I added some code of the login pipe and as I mention, I'm reading that my problem may be the bad use of connections

Comment: 3rd screenshot, get the caught  exception to get details, and return 522 to check if error is here

Comment: Please do not post images for text data, just copy paste the text instead.

Comment: There are probably logs on the backend side that tells what happened.

Comment: Have you looked at your slow query log in MySQL?